# How to select highlighted option automatically/programmatically (jquery select2)?

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

When I enter something in search area in select2 field, a result comes up as highlighhted.  I want to add the highlighted option as selected and update rendered area, not clicking via mouse. How to do this?

[image]

Comment: Please show us what you have tried yourself inorder to create this.

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://select2.org/advanced/default-adapters/results)?

Comment: `update rendered area` what do you mean with this? Should this only happen if you have 1 result or how would you go and select an option if you have mutliple if not via clicking?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the option `selectOnClose`: https://select2.org/dropdown#automatic-selection. Is it close enough?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".js-example-basic-single").select2({
    selectOnClose: true
  });
        
});
```

```css
.js-example-basic-single{
 width:150px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" id="mySelect2">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Actually I want to use "selectOnClose" function. But when try to use it, mouse cursor starts to circling and continues apprx. 20 seconds then stops. If this function opretaes/finishes this process in 20 seconds I think this is a big problem. Is it normal?

Comment: @orcun I don't think it's normal but I don't know what's causing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var data = [
    {
        id: "AL",
        text: 'Alabama'
    },
    {
        id: "AK",
        text: 'Alaska'
    },
    {
        id: "IL",
        text: 'Illinois'
    },
    {
        id: "MN",
        text: 'Minnesota'
    },
    {
        id: "WY",
        text: 'Wyoming'
    }
];
    $('body').on('keyup', '.select2-search__field', function() {
      var searchTerm = $(this).val();
      
      var returnedData = $.grep(data, function (element, index) {
          return element.text.toLowerCase() == searchTerm.toLowerCase();
      });
      
      if(returnedData.length) {
        $('#mySelect2').val(returnedData[0].id);
        $('#mySelect2').trigger('change');
        $('#mySelect2').select2('close');
      }
      
    });

    $("#mySelect2").select2({
      matcher: matchCustom,
      data: data,
      placeholder: "Select a state",
      language:{
        noResults : function () { return ''; }
      }
    });
        
    function matchCustom(params, data) {
    // If there are no search terms, return all of the data
    if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
      return data;
    }

    // Do not display the item if there is no 'text' property
    if (typeof data.text === 'undefined') {
      return null;
    }

    // Return `null` if the term should not be displayed
    return data;
  }
          
});
```

```css
.js-example-basic-single{
 width:150px;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.8/js/select2.min.js"></script>


<select class="js-example-basic-single" name="state" id="mySelect2">
  <option></option>
</select>
```